# AS2 ExternalInterface: Error: An invalid exception was thrown

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-2

I'm currently trying to do something with Flash and javascript using ExternalInterface.

As soon as the javascript function is executed, and with a callback should send something to Flash, the following error appears in my browser console:

Error: An invalid exception was thrown.

Here is the code:

```
//JavaScript:
var obj = swfobject.getObjectById("flash-wrapper");
obj.sendLogin(this.getCookie("username"), this.getCookie("password"));

//ActionScript 2:
ExternalInterface.addCallback('sendLogin', __reg2, __reg2.sendLogin);
ExternalInterface.call('init');
```

I would be happy about help. I try to solve this problem in the meantime for 2 hours.

Answer (score 0):

I have a same problem, but in as3. My trouble was that callback function in action script was **private** . I set it in public and exception disapper.

And check in AS:

1. Security.allowDomain("*");
2. ExternalInterface.available

And in js check, that you get right flash object: for example, in chrome get object after

```
<!--[if !IE]>-->
```